# Laravel & JS: Making a GET request with 2 variables

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-blade

My Laravel controler has the following function:

```
function products($collectionName) {

    ////
}
```

In my routes file, it is:

```
Route::get('admin/toys/collections/products/{collectionName}', 'Admin\ToysController@products');
```

I've since added a 2nd optional param to `products` so that it is now:

```
function products($collectionName, $quantity=null) {

}
```

**Blade file**
I am trying to make an AJAX request in the blade but I don't know how to pass in the fields since there are now 2 -- is this possible without making it into a POST request now?

```
  <?php $collectionName = "testing"; 
         $quantity = "55"
   ?>

    $.ajax({
       type:'get',
       url: 'admin/toys/collections/products/' + {{ $collectionName }}
    )}
```

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/routing#parameters-optional-parameters

Answer (score 0):

In your route define your optional parameter according to laravel docs

```
Route::get('admin/toys/collections/products/{collectionName}/{quantity?}', 'Admin\ToysController@products');
```

So when you pass quantity value it will take your value or else consider it as null.